# Closest("tr") getting always 1st row's value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo Grid. When a row is selected I need the data in that row, but for some reason whichever row I select, I am getting the data from only 1st row.

Here is my Code.

```
var CustomerGrid = $("#TransHistoryGrid").data().kendoGrid;
FName = CustomerGrid .dataItem($(this).closest("tr")).FirstName;
```

Please help.

Comment: Please post more code. Create a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: What is `this` at the time that second line executes?

Answer (score 3):

The way Kendo works, if you set the row to selectable.

```
var grid = $("#TransHistoryGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var dataItem = grid.select();
var firstName = dataItem.FirstName;
```

You only use the closest("tr") if you have a command button on the row and you apply a click event.

```
command.Custom("Edit Field").Click("EditField");

function EditField(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var firstName = dataItem.FirstName;
}
```

Comment: Note that if you're using ASP.NET Core MVC, and you specify an <editable> taghelper, the closest tr trick does not work for some reason.